# Add both UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd and UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash to one side of a Navigation Item or a UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol, uinavigationitem

I'd like to have a `UIViewController` which has an Add and a Trash button both right to the title, either by adding two `UIBarButtonItems` to the navigation item/bar or by adding them to a `UISegmentedControl` and then adding the SegmentedControl to the item. Is this possible? If yes, how is it achieved best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar. I've added two UIButtons to a navigation item/bar by creating a UIView subclass that has two UIButtons in it. You can then do something like this:

```
MyUIViewSubclass *tempview = [[[MyUIViewSubclass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(234,4,84,30)] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem newButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tempview] autorelease];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:newButton animated:NO];
```

All you have to do is layout the buttons in `MyUIViewSubclass` and you're good.

Also, I pass the ID of the target along in a customized init command to make for easier targeting of the buttons in the view. So for `MyUIViewSubclass` instead of `initWithFrame`, I have something like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect andTarget:(id)newTarget {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:aRect]) {



        UIButton *editbtn = [[[UIButton alloc]  initWithFrame:fframe] autorelease];
        [editbtn addTarget:newTarget action:@selector(MBEdit) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self addSubview:editbtn];
        [self setFirstbutton:editbtn];
        [editbtn release];



        UIButton *newbtn = [[[UIButton alloc]  initWithFrame:fframe] autorelease];
        [newbtn addTarget:newTarget action:@selector(MBNew) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self addSubview:newbtn];
        [self setSecondbutton:newbtn];
        [newbtn release];

    }

    return self;

}
```

Comment: But I'd still have to paint the UIButtons myself to have them look like the navigation bar buttons, right? I'd be perfectly happy to use a UISegmentedControl (which would save me the painting hassle) - but what I really need are the + and the original iPhone trash can icons. I'd prefer an even more elegant solution (like having some Unicode letter codes for the bold + and the trash can), though.

Comment: I actually just took a screenshot and used the image for my buttons. I'm almost certain that you can also just add a segmented control to the view instead of two buttons. That would work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple buttons to a navigation item by wrapping them in a `UIToolbar`, [sample code](http://gist.github.com/558688).